# How to validate epoch time with datetime using XSLT1.0/2.0?

Tags: xslt

I was wondering if we can validate epoch time with date time? I am getting a simple JWT token

```
{
    "iss": "SOS",
    "sub": "SOS",
    "iat": 1522944892,
    "exp": 1522945492,
    "dfp": "123"
}
```

Extracting the exp string is easy but I was wondering how to validate using date time?

Update: validating the exp time with ttl is 600s

Comment: Which XSLT processor, which version of XSLT can you use?

Comment: And what exactly does validating mean, which result do you want?

Comment: @martin My apology. XSLT 1.0/2.0 will work. I am basically validating the expiration of the token where TTL is 600s

Comment: I think you can construct an XSLT/XPath 2.0 `xs:dateTime` from your epoch value with e.g. `xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00') + 1522945492 * xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')`, still not sure whether you want to compare that to the `iat` value or where the `600s` you mention come from.